# class giving an error and not running?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

So i have just learned how to use classes and i made this class but i can't make it to run i use

```
spacecraft1 = spacecraft(500,500,100,34)
```

to make the class
then on loop i use `spacecraft1.motion()` to update / move. From all of this i get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Redstone3\Desktop\Desctop\Centers\game5\gameBuild 0.04.py", line 107, in <module>
    spacecraft1 = spacecraft(500,500,100,34)
TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not callable
```

and is it possible to create like 40 of these spaceships at same time without defining everyone of them like

```
spacecraft1 = spacecraft(500,500,100,34)
spacecraft2 = spacecraft(500,500,100,34)
spacecraft3 = spacecraft(500,500,100,34)
spacecr...
```

Here is my class if it helps something. And this class and the main gamefile are in seperate files but in same folders.

```
import pygame
import random



class BaseClass(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

 allsprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
 def __init__(self, x, y, width, height,):


    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    BaseClass.allsprites.add(self)



    self.shipDefaultUp = pygame.image.load("textures/ships/shipDefault/shipUP.png")
    self.shipDefaultRight = pygame.image.load("textures/ships/shipDefault/shipRIGHT.png")
    self.shipDefaultDown = pygame.image.load("textures/ships/shipDefault/shipDOWN.png")
    self.shipDefaultLeft = pygame.image.load("textures/ships/shipDefault/shipLEFT.png")

    self.shipCargo1Up = pygame.image.load("textures/ships/shipCargo1/shipCargo1UP.png")
    self.shipCargo1Right = pygame.image.load("textures/ships/shipCargo1/shipCargo1RIGHT.png")
    self.shipCargo1Down = pygame.image.load("textures/ships/shipCargo1/shipCargo1DOWN.png")
    self.shipCargo1Left = pygame.image.load("textures/ships/shipCargo1/shipCargo1LEFT.png")

    self.shipCargo2Up = pygame.image.load("textures/ships/shipCargo2/shipCargo2UP.png")
    self.shipCargo2Right = pygame.image.load("textures/ships/shipCargo2/shipCargo2RIGHT.png")
    self.shipCargo2Down = pygame.image.load("textures/ships/shipCargo2/shipCargo2DOWN.png")
    self.shipCargo2Left = pygame.image.load("textures/ships/shipCargo2/shipCargo2LEFT.png")



    self.image = pygame.image.load("textures/ships/shipDefault/shipUP.png")

    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.x = x
    self.rect.y = y

    self.width = width
    self.height = height

    #self.dirrection = random.randrange(1,5)
    self.dirrection = 1
    self.timer = random.randrange(10,50)
    self.speed = random.randrange(2,10)

    self.shiptype = 3#random.randrange(1,3)

    #shiptypes#
    #1 = shipDefault
    #2 = shipCargo1
    #3 = shipCargo2



    self.move1 = ((1),(2),(4))
    self.move2 = ((1),(2),(3))
    self.move3 = ((2),(3),(4))
    self.move4 = ((1),(3),(4))

class spacecraft(BaseClass):
    ships = pygame.sprite.Group()



    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height,):
        BaseClass.__init__(self, x, y, width, height,)
        spacecraft.ships.add(self)

    def motion(self):

        #1 = UP
        #2 = RIGHT
        #3 = DOWN
        #4 = LEFT


        self.timer -=1

        if self.dirrection == 1: ##############SHIP UP
            self.rect.y -=self.speed

            if self.shiptype == 1:
                self.image = self.shipDefaultUp

            if self.shiptype == 2:
                self.image = self.shipCargo1Up



        if self.dirrection == 2:################SHIP RIGHT
            self.rect.x +=self.speed

            if self.shiptype == 1:
                self.image = self.shipDefaultRight

            if self.shiptype == 2:
                self.image = self.shipCargo1Right

            if self.shiptype == 3:
                self.image = self.shipCargo2Right



        if self.dirrection == 3: ##############SHIP DOWN
            self.rect.y +=self.speed

            if self.shiptype == 1:
                self.image = self.shipDefaultDown

            if self.shiptype == 2:
                self.image = self.shipCargo1Down

            if self.shiptype == 3:
                self.image = self.shipCargo2Down


        if self.dirrection == 4: ################SHIP LEFT
            self.rect.x -=self.speed

            if self.shiptype == 1:
                self.image = self.shipDefaultLeft

            if self.shiptype == 2:
                self.image = self.shipCargo1Left

            if self.shiptype == 3:
                self.image = self.shipCargo2Left



        if self.dirrection == 5:   ####IF SHIP IS NOT MOVING####
            print("loitter")

        if self.timer < 0:####GET NEW DIRECTION FOR SHIP####
            self.dirrection = random.randrange(1,6)
            self.timer = random.randrange(10,50)
```

[Full code here(Google Drive)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0f7yu0UP963Y1lYcV9XRUFtU00/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: For the easy question: you can use a `list` to create a bunch of spaceships and store them all in one variable.

Comment: use `CamelCase` names for classes - `class Spacecraft(BaseClass):` - it makes code more readable.

Comment: how like? `epicList = []` and what then? do i need to use something like `spacecraft1.append?`

Comment: You can use list like `all_spacecrafts = []` and `all_spacecrafts.append`. Or use `Group` - `all_spacecrafts = pygame.sprite.Group()`

Comment: `error` looks like you assign some value to `pygame.Surface` - `ie. 'pygame.Surface = some_value` - and now it can use it as class `pygame.Surface(...)`

Comment: you can use `print( type(spacecraft) )` before `spacecraft1 = spacecraft(500,500,100,34)` to check what type is `spacecraft` at that moment.

Comment: It prints out that `<class 'pygame.Surface'>` and so what should `pygame.Surface` be? should it be like? `pygame.Surface = 15` or?
does this have anything to do with that i have `screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1600, 1000))` is that some how connected with surface or am i fully wrong?

Comment: Ok so what do i do so i can get this class to show and running just cant fiqure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the error says "surface object not callable" that means at some point in your function where you think you are instantiating an instance of spacecraft, you have previously created a local variable containing a pygame.Surface object that overrides the class "spacecraft" from the global scope. Your class is not where the problem is, it's the previous code in the function where you're trying to instantiate it.

e.g.

```
 class spacecraft:
   ...

 def someOtherFunction:
    ...
    # this valid line of code is actually where the problem 
    # is as it hides your spacecraft class with a local variable instead.
    spacecraft = some pygame.Surface instance
    ...
    spacecraft1 = spacecraft(...)
    ...
```

Comment: So if i got this right something is overriding pygame.Surface?

Comment: No. I've updated my response to illustrate what is likely going on.

Comment: i'v got nothing on my classes/def's that should reinstate that  `spacecraft = something else` atleast i can't see it. All my classes are on my main post.

Comment: Because i made this class first in diffrent file/program because it was easier to test it on other code first

Comment: I put the hole main code here
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0f7yu0UP963Y1lYcV9XRUFtU00/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: This line: `spacecraft = pygame.image.load("textures/icons/shipRIGHT.png")`

Comment: Ok this seems to work perfectly when i looked it should have been obvious

Comment: @cmdtvt: One way to help avoid accidents like this in the future is to follow standard Python naming conventions. For example, local variables should always begin with a lowercase and class names should always begin with an uppercase. That way hiding a class name with a local variable will be impossible.

Comment: Ye using CamelCase would be smart :P  Gonna start using that know